# Unexpected string split behaviour

Tags: string, rust, split, iterator

I am reading rustbook and came across the following piece of code:

```rust
fn main() {
    "Hello, world!".split("#").next().expect("some message");
}
```

I ran it, but the program didn't panic, although there is no such symbol in the string and the iterator should have returned None when calling next().

After that I went to [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split) and for some reason I didn't find an example with splitting by a pattern which doesn't exist in the string.

Please explain why None is not returned in this case.

Comment: I'm not a Rust expert by any means, but surely the iterator first produces the entire `Hello, world!` string before running out of input, so `next` will only fail the second time, not the first? Note that those docs *do* give a similar example (splitting an empty string at a nonexistent character), where when collecting the results of the iterator you get a single element containing the whole string.

Comment: Thank you. I get it. It's just that in [this example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-annotations-in-struct-definitions) the error message really confused me and the documentation doesn't tell me clearly how exactly the split string is collected.

Comment: I see, thanks. Yes, that error message is confusing as it won't be triggered even if there is no `.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"Hello, world!".split("#")` successfully splits the string at *every* occurrence of `#`. If there are N hash signs in the string, then the resulting iterator will iterate over N+1 delimited substrings. In your case, there are 0 hash signs, so you get one substring: namely, the whole string itself.